# spring enforce transactional logic for annotated method

Tags: java, spring

I have some method that is annotated with `@Transactional` annotation. This method is not called through spring generated proxy but I need somehow enforce transaction creation without using that proxy.

Is it possible to implement?

Comment: What about using [`TransactionTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html)? If you are insterested I will expand it into an answer and provide some more details.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz, TransactionTemplate helped me to solve my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`TransactionTemplate`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) to start  transaction manually in provided code block/callback:

```
final TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);

transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<String>()
{
    @Override
    public String doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status)
    {
        //...
        return "Some result";
    }
});
```

Or if you don't need a result:

```
transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult()
{
    @Override
    protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status)
    {
        //...
    }
});
```

Of course you can also define `TransactionTemplate` as a Spring bean and inject it directly. Otherwise you can create it every time you need it but then you need to inject transaction manager:

```
@Resource
private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;
```